# Why converting a float list into numpy array changes the value of some variables?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, scikit-learn

So I have following code snippet:

```
with open('dataset/train/problem.csv', 'r') as p:
raw_x = csv.reader(p)
data_x = []
for ix in raw_x:
    data_x.append([float(i) for i in ix])
print(data_x)
```

This prints the following output:

```
[[217.0, 118.0, 0.63, 755.0, 1071.0], [217.0, 118.0, 0.63, 755.0, 1071.0],...]
```

Now I am trying to convert this structure into a numpy array of floats so that I can use it with scikit-learn as an observation input. But when I try doing following

```
X = np.array(data_x)
print(X)
```

It gives the following result:

```
[  2.17000000e+02   1.18000000e+02   6.30000000e-01   7.55000000e+02
1.07100000e+03]
...
[  2.17000000e+02   1.18000000e+02   6.30000000e-01   7.55000000e+02
1.07100000e+03]
```

It's still float but the decimal values are not correct.

Been trying to figure out why this is happening as the source array is also in floats. I have tried providing `type=float` and `astype` as well but nothing seems to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in the array are the same. For example, `2.1700000000e+2` is `2.17 x 10^2`, or `217`, which is the same as in your original array.

The numpy array uses scientific notation instead of standard decimal form.

Comment: I am not very experienced with it, but I believe so.

Answer (score 0):

The values are the same in the list and the array. It is just a different representation.

You can format a Python float in scientific notation:

```
>>> '{:e}'.format(11.7)
'1.170000e+01'
```

NumPy uses this kind of representation. That's all.

Comment: Yes. NumPy arrays can be used with most (all?) Python packages that work with array data types.