# Using vstack to stack arrays on python but the floats change to scientific notation

Tags: python, floating-point, scientific-notation

I have a few nice arrays of floats that end with .0, and I would like to merge them together. However, when I do so using numpy vstack, it adds 0s to the end of the floating number, causing it to be written in scientific notation.

```
 [ 24.   5.]
 [  8.   5.]
 [ 18.   0.]
 [  0.   5.]
 [  9.   1.]
 ...
```

becomes

```
 [  2.40000000e+01   5.00000000e+00]
 [  8.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+00]
 [  1.80000000e+01   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+00]
 [  9.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]
 ...
```

my code:

```
merged = np.vstack((twocol, merged))
```

I am essentially stacking more arrays into a bigger array called merged.
Does anyone know any solution?

Comment: What's the problem? The numbers are the same...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why converting a float list into numpy array changes the value of some variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34960210/why-converting-a-float-list-into-numpy-array-changes-the-value-of-some-variables)